# XamComboEditor SelectedItemChangedEvent firing non-stop in XamDataGrid

Tags: infragistics, xamdatagrid, selecteditemchanged

I have bound XamComboEditor's in two columns of XamDataGrid. When I select an item from XamComboEditor1, I would like to bind specific items to XamComboEditor2. I have attached SelectedItemChanged Event to XamComboEditor1. The event fires non-stop on selecting an item.

XAML-

```
 <Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:igDP="http://infragistics.com/DataPresenter"
    xmlns:igRibbon="http://infragistics.com/Ribbon"
    xmlns:igOB="http://infragistics.com/OutlookBar"
    xmlns:igDock="http://infragistics.com/DockManager"
    xmlns:igTiles="http://infragistics.com/Tiles"
    xmlns:igEditors="http://infragistics.com/Editors"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="720">
    <Window.Resources>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Margin="0,26,0,-26">
            <igDP:XamDataGrid x:Name="XamDataGrid1">
            </igDP:XamDataGrid>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code Behind -

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Infragistics.Windows.DataPresenter;
using Infragistics.Windows.Editors;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
  /// </summary>
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
    public MainWindow()
    {
      InitializeComponent();

      EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(ValueEditor),
                    ValueEditor.ValueChangedEvent,
                    new RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler<object>(OnValueChanged));

      ComboBoxItemsProvider provider = new ComboBoxItemsProvider();
      for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        provider.Items.Add(new ComboBoxDataItem(i, "Item " + i.ToString()));

      FieldLayout fieldLayout = new FieldLayout();

      UnboundField fld1 = new UnboundField();
      fld1.Name = "Visibility Setting1";
      Style style1 = new Style(typeof(XamComboEditor));
      style1.Setters.Add(new Setter(XamComboEditor.ItemsProviderProperty, provider));
      style1.Setters.Add(new EventSetter(XamComboEditor.SelectedItemChangedEvent, new RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler<object>(XamComboEditor1_SelectedItemChanged)));
      fld1.Settings.EditorStyle = style1;
      fld1.Settings.EditorType = typeof(XamComboEditor);

      fieldLayout.Fields.Add(fld1);

      UnboundField fld2 = new UnboundField();
      fld2.Name = "Visibility Setting2";
      Style style2 = new Style(typeof(XamComboEditor));
      fld2.Settings.EditorStyle = style2;
      fld2.Settings.EditorType = typeof(XamComboEditor);
      fieldLayout.Fields.Add(fld2);

      this.XamDataGrid1.FieldLayouts.Add(fieldLayout);
      this.XamDataGrid1.BindToSampleData = true;
    }

    void OnValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
    {
      if (sender is XamComboEditor || sender is XamCheckEditor || sender is XamDateTimeEditor)
      {
        (sender as ValueEditor).EndEditMode(true, true);

        if (sender is XamComboEditor)
        {
          XamComboEditor comboEditor = (XamComboEditor)sender;
        }
      }
    }


    private void XamComboEditor1_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
    {
      // Create combo box items provider for freight modes
      ComboBoxItemsProvider provider = new ComboBoxItemsProvider();
      for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
      {
        provider.Items.Add(new ComboBoxDataItem(i.ToString(), i.ToString()));
      }

      //// Get unbound field associated with index
      Record record = this.XamDataGrid1.ActiveRecord;

      // Get the combo editor with record
      UnboundField uFld = (UnboundField)record.FieldLayout.Fields[1];

      // Set style for uFld
      Style style = new Style(typeof(XamComboEditor));
      style.Setters.Add(new Setter(XamComboEditor.ItemsProviderProperty, provider));
      style.Setters.Add(new Setter(XamComboEditor.DropDownResizeModeProperty, Infragistics.Windows.Controls.PopupResizeMode.None));
      style.Setters.Add(new Setter(XamComboEditor.IsAlwaysInEditModeProperty, false));
      style.Setters.Add(new EventSetter(XamComboEditor.SelectedItemChangedEvent, new RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler<object>(XamComboEditor2_SelectedItemChanged)));
      style.Setters.Add(new Setter(XamComboEditor.IsEditableProperty, false));
      uFld.Settings.EditorStyle = style;
      uFld.Settings.EditorType = typeof(XamComboEditor);
      uFld.Settings.InvalidValueBehavior = InvalidValueBehavior.RetainValue;
      uFld.Settings.AllowCellVirtualization = false;

      e.Handled = true;
    }

    private void XamComboEditor2_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
    {
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Kindly help. Stuck in this problem for few hours.

Comment: Any Infragistics guru(s) around to answer the question. Kindly help

Comment: Anybody anybody anybody ....please

Comment: Found the solution...Thanks to this link http://blogsprajeesh.blogspot.com/2010/03/infragistics-working-with-2.html

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't be referring back to the style in the unbound field.

Found solution at -

http://blogsprajeesh.blogspot.com/2010/03/infragistics-working-with-2.html